# Is this a violation of the law of demand?

Tags: microeconomics, supply-and-demand

Beach resorts typically raise their prices during the summer months and yet more people book rooms at those times. Is this a violation of the law of demand? If so, why?  If not, how would you be able to explain what is happening with a supply and demand model (i.e. please explain in words which curve(s) might be changing)?

As the price of 4DTVs has fallen over the last several years, more 4DTVs have been sold by consumer electronics firms. Is this a violation of the law of supply?  If so, why?  If not, how would you be able to explain what is happening with a supply and demand model (i.e. please explain in words which curve(s) might be changing)?

Comment: Consider adding your attempt to work out a solution in your next questions , otherwise you could attract downvotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the first one : if the demand rises, it moves to the right on the plane , so the new price will be higher because the supply curve remains (almost) the same.

The demand will be higher because the utility function of a beach hotel will be higher for all people during summer months.

(The second one is similar. Can you come up with an explanation yourself?)

Therefore, they aren't violations of the law of demand and supply.